# Decoding NHL JSON table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to scrape nhl statistics from the nhl statistics database (http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/playerstatsline/20142015/2/OTT/iphone/playerstatsline.json) and then separating the table into an array of players, with the tuples (number, goals, assists, points, penalty minutes,etc.) and then adding them to an SQL database. So far, I've been able to get the information from the page, and I think I've turned it into an array, but I can't seem to divide it up into individual players, and their respectives stats.
This is what I've got so far: (Not much)

```
$url =    'http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/playerstatsline/20142015/2/OTT/iphone/playerstatsline.json';
$output = file_get_contents($url); 
$data = json_decode($output, true);
echo $output;
echo $data;
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question my friend.

Comment: So you've decoded it. Now what?

Comment: I'm sort of - brand new to php. I'm not really sure what do with the decoded info. How do I extract, say, Erik Karlsson's Goals and Assist totals?

Comment: Sounds like you need a better PHP reference. Do you know how to navigate through typical PHP array structures?

Comment: Not a clue. I'm familiar with arrays in C, Java and Python though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the data using the array notation (`$data['fieldName']`), so for your JSON you could loop through each skater as follows;

```
foreach($data['skaterData'] as $sktr) {
    echo $sktr['id'] . " " . $sktr['data'];
}
```

You can then use the values in `$sktr[]` for each skater inside the loop as you see fit. You will always be able to directly access other values in the decoded data, such as `$data['timestamp']`.

If you remove the `true` from the `$data = json_decode($output, true);` then you should use the object notaion

```
foreach($data->skaterData as $sktr) {
    echo $sktr->id . " " . $sktr->data;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I implemented that in my code, by I keep generating this error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sktr' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/matt/public_html/school/index.php on line 7.
What could be the issue?

Comment: Ok, I plugged that in, but now I'm getting this error - Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/matt/public_html/school/index.php on line 6

Comment: OK, comment my code out for the moment (`/*` and `*/` around the code) and put in `print_r($data);`. Update your answer with the result.

Comment: It won't let me post it as a comment, so here's a link to the page - http://mattegener.me/school/

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. The data is in arrays (which is not how it should be structured, but that's the source's fault, not your's). One moment, and I'll update my answer.

Comment: OK, there we go. You should be able to use the array notation instead.

Comment: I just noticed you've used the array converter argument in your `json_decode`. If you do that then you need to use the array notation, if you remove it (or change it to false) you should use the object notation. I've put both in my updated answer.

Comment: Excellent, that seem to be working well. How would I extract (just as an example for the rest) only the goals from this? Say I just wanted to print out each player's goals total (Will later be put into an SQL query)?

Comment: In the data you can [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) out the strings and deal with them as you see fit. For example (inside the loop), `$sdata = explode(",", $sktr['data']);` will give you an array of the strings that are separated by each `,` in the JSON. I don't know which are goals (I'm British), but you can loop through the data with a `foreach` loop similar to that in the answer; or if you know the index (number) then you can access it with `$sdata[4]` (where `4` is the 5th element in the array).

Comment: Awesome. Thank you some much for your help. I'm actually blown away by how helpful StackOverflow has been. Hopefully there are lots of helpful people like you out there :)

Comment: I've got everything working now, but I can't seem to create new lines with print or echo statements (I'm trying to neaten it up). Any tips?

Comment: @mattegener As PHP is a web programming language, and the result is seen in a web browser, you need to use HTML markup to create lines, paragraphs, tables, etc. Plenty of stuff on the web about HTML, but `<br>` will put the next content on a new line.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I have some experience with HTML, but I didn't realize that the <br \> had to be put quotations. I think I've got the issue resolved.

Answer (score 2):

At first, you have an error in your source url. There is example how you can fill an array of players with their data in array.

```
$url = 'http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/playerstatsline/20142015/2/OTT/iphone/playerstatsline.json';
$output = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($output);


$skatersData = array();
foreach($data->skaterData as $sktr) {
    $skatersData[$sktr->id] = explode(',', $sktr->data);
}

var_dump($skatersData);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. What exactly does the var_dump statement do?

Comment: It is just for print structure of finally array with values. There is no need to use this statement. Actually, don't use this line in your production code. It's only for stand alone example.